# Reshape dataframe based on column prefixes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that I read into a dataframe that looks like the following

```
    Time  AP1  AQ1  AP2  AQ2  AP3  AQ3  AP4  AQ4  AP5  AQ5
0   2000  100   10  300   30  500   50  700   70  900   90
1   2001  105   15  305   35  505   55  705   75  905   95
2   2002  110   20  310   40  510   60  710   80  910  100
3   2003  115   25  315   45  515   65  715   85  915  105
4   2004  120   30  320   50  520   70  720   90  920  110
5   2005  125   35  325   55  525   75  725   95  925  115
```

How do I reshape the dataframe without using loops such that I only have the columns Time, AP and AQ?

```
    Time  AP    AQ
0   2000  100   10
0   2000  300   30
0   2000  500   50  
0   2000  700   70
0   2000  900   90
1   2001  105   15
....
```

Thank you for much in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) setting `AP` and `AQ` as `stubnames`:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['AP','AQ'], i='Time', j='j')
   .droplevel(1).reset_index())

    Time   AP   AQ
0   2000  100   10
1   2001  105   15
2   2002  110   20
3   2003  115   25
4   2004  120   30
5   2005  125   35
6   2000  300   30
7   2001  305   35
8   2002  310   40
9   2003  315   45
10  2004  320   50
11  2005  325   55
12  2000  500   50
13  2001  505   55
14  2002  510   60
15  2003  515   65
```

---

**Update**

For a `Time` column with duplicates, you can do:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['AP','AQ'], i='index', j='j')
  .reset_index(drop=True))

    Time  AP   AQ
0   2000  100   10
1   2000  105   15
2   2002  110   20
3   2003  115   25
4   2004  120   30
5   2005  125   35
6   2000  300   30
7   2000  305   35
8   2002  310   40
9   2003  315   45
10  2004  320   50
11  2005  325   55
12  2000  500   50
```

Comment: Thanks!! A follow up question though, I realise my data may not have unique Time for each row, i.e. both first and 2nd rows could have time 2000. In that case I got an error "the id variables need to uniquely identify each row". I tried several ways but could not resolve it. Would you have any suggestions?